# Reading Java system properties from command line

Tags: java, environment-variables

Is there a better way to print system properties from command line? As we can set the property e.g.

```
 java  -D<name>=<value>  //set a system property
```

Without writing a class to do that?

If not possible, why is it not possible/feasible/good to do that from the command line ?

Comment: A system property is set when starting the JVM. Before that there is nothing to read.

Comment: Do you want to be able to distinguish between default system properties and those set/overridden via the command line?

Comment: Are you asking how to read system properties?

Comment: I need to know what are certain directories set e.g what is extension directory set currently

Comment: You may wish to read [System Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) and [The Extension Mechanism Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/extensions/spec.html) if you haven't already, or you might just leap right in and try `System.getProperty("java.ext.dirs")`.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can use the `-XshowSettings` flag in the Hotspot JVM version 1.7 and up (not supported in 1.6):

```
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

OpenJDK has had support for this flag since late 2010.

Seen in http://marxsoftware.blogspot.de/2016/02/hotspot-jvm-XshowSettings.html

**EDIT 14 Dec 2016**

The Oracle JVM ships with the tool jcmd which allows you to see the flags present in a running JVM. See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html

For this use case, you could use:

```
jcmd <pid> VM.system_properties
```

But there are also many other useful commands. For example:

```
jcmd <pid> VM.flags
jcmd <pid> VM.command_line
jcmd <pid> GC.run
```

Comment: It seems like `VM.system_properties` only prints "well known" properties. Is there a way to view properties that the user has created?

Comment: I don't know. I suggest you to post a question and link it to this one.

Comment: how to get system properties in linux machine

Comment: I take it back, on my local Mac, I see system properties that are specific to my app.

Answer (score 31):

You can use [jps](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) a tool that comes with the jdk. 
It can print out the system properties that were passed to a java process.

For example: On my system eclipse is running and

```
$ jps -v
```

outputs

```
6632  -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

`jps` is located in `JDK_HOME/bin`

**EDIT**

If you want all the properties use the [jinfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jinfo.html) tool that is also located in `JDK_HOME/bin`. To use it you must know the process id of the java process you want to get information from. E.g.

```
$ jinfo 6632
```

This tool also prints out the `java.ext.dirs`

Comment: how to get the value of `java.ext.dirs` ?

Answer (score 5):

If you need defaults that your JVM will initially have set unless overridden, use:

```sh
java -XshowSettings:properties -version
```

This is helpful if you don't have a Java application already running, thus no pid to pass to one of the other commands.

If you are seeking the properties of a JVM already running that has properties set via default or set explicitly by command, then use the pid for that JVM found via `jps` with the `jcmd` or `jinfo` commands as listed in answers above.

Answer (score 0):

Before `jcmd` times one can use JMX management connection from VisualVM. It is UI app so you have to expose JMX port from your remote headless servers to the that info...

JMX settings might look like:

```bash
JAVA_OPT="$JAVA_OPT
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=localhost
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No parsing is required.

```
jshell --feedback=silent -  <<< 'System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"))'
```